# Place independent view file into a div in another html in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to place a view in `<div>` of another view in code-igniter

**views/parent_view.php**

```
<div id="my_div" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Main Div</h3>
  <p>Main Div content.</p>
</div>
```

My requirement is to place

**views/child_view.php**

```html
<html>
      <head>
       Child 1
      </head>
      <body>
       I am child one
      </body>
    </html>
```

**controllers/child_view_controller.php**

```
 function loadview(){

      $data['result'] = '';//
      print $this->load->view('child_view',$data,true);
 }
```

the above function called using ajax

```
$.ajax({
             url: base_url+'index.php/child_view/loadview',
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'html',
             success: function (html) {
                $("#my_div").html=html;


             }
        });
```

I am getting entire html in response but nothing will change in parent view

Comment: $("#my_div").html(html);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try and answer this question. If i understand you properly, you want to load the response from the ajax request into a parent div. if that is what you want to do, then this should help.

```
<!--  this is your parent view -->
<div id="my_div" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Main Div</h3>
    <p>Main Div content.</p>
</div>
```

Next is your javascript code

```
<!-- this is your ajax -->
$.ajax({
    url: base_url+'index.php/child_view_controller/loadview',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        $("#my_div").html(response); // this replaces the children of #my_div with the response received from the php
    }
});
```

And then your php code that loads the required view

```
// and this is your php
function loadview(){
  $data['result'] = '';
  $this->load->view('child_view', $data, true);
}
```

I believe your problem is found in your javascript code, at the point where u replaced the children of the my_div Id with the ajax success response. So basically I just redid what you did, but changed some few lines, check it out and let me know whether it was of help to you.

Comment: $("#my_div").html(html);

Comment: It is worked,Thank you .Only change is $("#my_div").html(html);